# How can I make QtCreator break on exceptions?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I am Debugging some BOOST unit tests in QtCreator and it sadly happened that they crash with an exception. How can I make QtCreator automagically break if any exception is raised? In Visual Studio there is a tick box for this one, is it also available in QtCreator?

In my case, BOOST catches the exception, so the program doesn't technically crash. However, the reported message is not really helpful.

I tried the same in KDevelop previuosly, hence I am asking separate questions about both of these IDEs.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

- Open Debug mode (Ctrl+F4 or just 4th mode on right bar).

  [image]
- Open context menu in breakpoints list at right bottom:

  [image]
- Select "Add Breakpoint" and set the breakpoint type to "Break when C++ exception is thrown":

  [image]

Comment: Is there a way to choose to break on a certain type/class of exception?

Comment: I have DEFINITELY checked the "C++ Exception" box in the "Break on:" category, but for some reason Qt Creator refuses to break on the exception. I know for a fact that an exception is being thrown because I have a "catch ( const std::exception& exc )" clause in which I print the return value of the exc object's what() method, and it says "std::bad_alloc". :(

Comment: I am seeing std::map trow an out_of_range exception, with the solution in the above answer enabled, yet QtCreator (4.11.1) still isn't breaking, just terminating the program =[

Comment: I have a similar problem with a Qtest Project. It seems that QTest  does not care about this setting

Answer (score 0):

In QTcreator 8.0.2, this worked for me without adding any additional breakpoints:

Edit --> preferences --> Debugger --> GDB Extended --> Enable "Stop when aport() is called"

[image]