# Qt Creator debugging in MSVC

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I use Qt 5.12.3, Qt Creator 4.9.1, MSVC 2017 x64 and debugger CDB.  I'm doing a step-by-step debugging of this code:

```
    try
    {
        int a(458);
        throw a;
    }
    catch(int& a)
    {
        qDebug() << a;
    }
```

An exception occurs and it is displayed:
[image]

But I don't hit the catch block, the app just stops. How to fix this problem? Thanks.

P.S.:
I saw [this message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735413/how-can-i-make-qtcreator-break-on-exceptions) and it does not work:
[image]

Comment: @AlexanderV  I saw this community and it does not work

Comment: What if `catch (int a)` without a reference? Otherwise the ref points to no longer valid stack. We have the debugger pointing at it.

Comment: @AlexanderV I removed the link, but this did not solve the problem