How to debug Qt with confusing traces. (No reference to own code in stack)
How to do or any tips on how to debug in situation like this, where C++ Qt GUI program crashes and stack has no clear reference to where the crash is coming from.
Is there some settings for QtCreator or some additional tools that could analyze the start point of the crash? I am assuming that it happens in other than main thread that causes it not to be displayed, but that is just a guess.

1 __GI_raise                    raise.c          51  0x7ffff2ddae87 
2 __GI_abort                    abort.c          79  0x7ffff2ddc7f1 
3 ??                                                 0x7ffff37cf957 
4 ??                                                 0x7ffff37d5ae6 
5 std::terminate()                                   0x7ffff37d5b21 
6 qTerminate()                                       0x7ffff3d73205 
7 QThreadPrivate::start(void *)                      0x7ffff3d93be7 
8 start_thread                  pthread_create.c 463 0x7ffff3ad36db 
9 clone                         clone.S          95  0x7ffff2ebd61f 

There is not any own code in stack trace and all is in dissasembled form.

I was expecting stacktrace to have startpoint to my own code where the crash started, but there is only library and system code.
The "4 ??" stack has some hints about the crash being pointer error, but I am not sure:

Thanks to @AlanBirtles, I also found the application output of the error, that might help me further.
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt.
You must not let any exception whatsoever propagate through Qt code.
If that is not possible, in Qt 5 you must at least reimplement
QCoreApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

Thank You.

Is there a message printed from the terminate?

@AlanBirtles Hi alan. Thank you. Yes there actually is, wonder how I missed it. Never seen a message like this before.
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt.
You must not let any exception whatsoever propagate through Qt code.
If that is not possible, in Qt 5 you must at least reimplement
QCoreApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc

One of your threads is throwing std::bad_alloc, you might have run out of memory but more likely you're trying to create a vector or something similar with a negative size. Please show a [mre]

Yes there surely is a bug in my code that throws the error. The original problem how ever kinda is a problem for the minimal reproducible example, because my stack trace does not have any reference to my own code lines that I could paste here.:

set a breakpoint on throwing exceptions to get a better stack trace

@AlanBirtles Do you mean by Inheriting QApplication and installing a a exception handler there and setting brake point there?

The bug in your code will involve (directly or indirectly) some form of new expression failing and throwing an exception.   If your code is not using new directly, it is using some standard library facility that is.   Possibilities include resizing (like Alan noted) or reserving capacity of a container like vector with a bad size (sizes of standard containers are represented using an unsigned type, so small negative values map to VERY large positive values), creating too many large objects with std::make_XXX  (e.g. std::make_unique), ....

No, whichever debugger you're using will be able to break on exceptions

Here is an old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735413/how-can-i-make-qtcreator-break-on-exceptions

@drescherjm This I think is correct answer for my debug problem. But I finally found the underlying excpetion causing problem by other code analyzis means and refactoring. For some reason the crash happened, if I sent a signal for for a object in an other thread and the signal containing QList<QObjectInherited*> parameter and using .contains(x) on that list in the slot caused crashing.

For that maybe attempt to create a [mcve] and ask a brand new question with the smaller yet still reproducing code.

The tool is called debugger and there is one in the QtCreator. Generally you start with what action triggers the crash, and then you can step by step follow code execution within this action until the crash happens so that you know which line is the last to be executed. Mind that it may not be the line causing the crash, especially when it's a pointer problem. However, the last line is probably the line that is doing something with the pointer. If you identified which pointer it is, you can now trace its usage across the program.
Easier way is to just start the debug and it should stop when the crash happens and give you the full trace. But that might not be the case. If you're using multithreading, look for race conditions as well.
It's generally not a good idea to have raw pointers at all.
